# How to post FormData object and additionaly object in one request?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have next code(frontend):

```
let imagesData = new FormData();

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
const data = {
    id: 5, 
    name: 'five'
}
uploadDataToServer(imagesData);
})
const uploadDataToServer = (data) => {
axios.post('http://localhost:5000/upload', data)
    .then((res) => console.log(res))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}
```

And next backend part:

```
app.post('/upload', upload.array('fileLoader', 5), (req, res, next) => {
    const files = req.files;
    if (!files) {
        const error = new Error('Please upload a file');
        error.httpStatusCode = 400;
        return next(error);
    }
    res.send(files);
})
```

How I can access object data in req.body and my images in req.files simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a new value to `imagesData` with the Formdata [set-function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/set).

```js
let imagesData = new FormData();

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  
  /*
   * Attention the set-funcetion sets a new value for an existing key 
   * or adds the key/value if it does not already exist
   */
  imagesData.set('id', 5);
  
  imagesData.set('name', 'five');
  
  uploadDataToServer(imagesData);
  
})
const uploadDataToServer = (data) => {
axios.post('http://localhost:5000/upload', data)
    .then((res) => console.log(res))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, how I can get access on backend to this fields?

Comment: Do you tried `req.id` or `req.name`? Do you tried to print out or debug the request on the server side?

Comment: Yes, but I got undefined in my console.log(req.id, req.name);

Comment: All right, thank you a lot, this fields were in req.body.